# How does ARIMA calculate the first few values of the model, i.e when $t < p,q$?

Tags: time-series, arima

If we have an $ARIMA(p,d,q)$ or $ARMA(p,q)$ model, how are the first few terms of the model for values of $t < p,q $ calculated?

Are the AR and MA terms for values of $p,q > t$ simply ignored until there is enough data to calculate them?  Or do we not start calculating values for the model until there enough data to do so?

Comment: What do you mean by _"terms"_? The very first samples in the series are surely used in the estimation of the model, even though they might not have associated predictions.